Error when saving TensorFlow model with preprocessing function: AttributeError: 'SymbolicTensor' object has no attribute 'tensor_shape'
I am trying to train a model on nyc taxi trip dataset.I have done my preprocessing in numpy and the training is also successful. I am encountering an error when attempting to save a TensorFlow model along with a custom preprocessing function. Here's an overview of my setup and the steps leading to the error:
# Import packages
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from datetime import datetime

# load data

train_ds = pd.read_csv(r"train.csv")

train_ind = int(train_ds.shape[0]*0.65)
val_ind = int(train_ds.shape[0]*0.20)
test_ind = int(train_ds.shape[0]*0.15)

val_ds = train_ds.iloc[train_ind:train_ind+val_ind,:]
val_ds = val_ds.copy()

test_ds = train_ds.iloc[train_ind+val_ind:,:]
test_ds = test_ds.copy()

train_ds = train_ds.iloc[:train_ind,:]
train_ds = train_ds.copy()

train_ds.drop(['dropoff_datetime'],axis=1,inplace=True)
val_ds.drop(['dropoff_datetime'],axis=1,inplace=True)
test_ds.drop(['dropoff_datetime'],axis=1,inplace=True)

X_train = train_ds.to_numpy()
X_val = val_ds.to_numpy()
X_test = test_ds.to_numpy()

# Building list of columns
time_cols = ['pickup_datetime']
long_lat_cols = ['pickup_longitude', 'pickup_latitude', 'dropoff_longitude', 'dropoff_latitude']
cat_cols = ['store_and_fwd_flag']
uw_cols = ['id','vendor_id']


def npre(df):
   vectorized_strptime = np.vectorize(lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
   x_date  = vectorized_strptime(df[:,2])
   vectorized_month = np.vectorize(lambda x: np.cos(x.month/12))
   x_month = vectorized_month(x_date)
   vectorized_day = np.vectorize(lambda x: np.cos(x.day/31))
   x_day = vectorized_day(x_date)
   vectorized_hour = np.vectorize(lambda x: np.cos(x.hour/24))
   x_hour = vectorized_hour(x_date)
   vectorized_minute = np.vectorize(lambda x: np.cos(x.minute/60))
   x_minute = vectorized_hour(x_date)
   x_ed = np.sqrt(np.square(df[:,4] - df[:,6]).astype(float) + np.square(df[:,5] - df[:,7]).astype(float))
   flag_unique_values = np.unique(df[:,8])
   encoded_arr = np.zeros((len(df), len(flag_unique_values)))
   for i, val in enumerate(df[:,8]):
      encoded_arr[i, np.where(flag_unique_values == val)[0][0]] = 1
   y = df[:,-1] 
   df = np.delete(df,[0,1,2,8],1)
   df = np.concatenate((df,np.expand_dims(x_month,axis=1),np.expand_dims(x_day,axis=1),np.expand_dims(x_hour,axis=1),np.expand_dims(x_minute,axis=1),np.expand_dims(x_ed,axis=1),encoded_arr),1)
  #  return df,y
   data = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((tf.convert_to_tensor(df.astype(float)),tf.convert_to_tensor(y.astype(float))))
   return data
  


train_data = npre(X_train)
val_data = npre(X_val)


inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(13,))
outputs = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)(inputs)
bl_model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)

bl_model.compile(
    loss = 'mse',
    optimizer= tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(),
    metrics = ['mae']
)

bl_model.summary()

history_bl = bl_model.fit(
    train_data,
    validation_data=val_data,
    epochs = 100,
)

def model_create():
    inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(13,))
    x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(8)(inputs)
    x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(16)(x)
    x = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5)(x)
    x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(32)(x)
    x = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5)(x)
    x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(64)(x)
    outputs = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)(x)
    model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)

    model.compile(
        loss = 'mse',
        optimizer= tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(),
        metrics = ['mae']
    )

    model.summary()
    return model

model = model_create()
history = model.fit(
    train_data,
    validation_data=val_data,
    epochs = 100,
    callbacks = [tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(filepath = r'model.weights.keras',monitor='val_mae',save_best_only=True)]
)


@tf.function(input_signature=[tf.TensorSpec(shape=(None, 13), dtype=tf.float32)])
def predict_with_preprocessing(input_data):
    preprocessed_input = npre(tf.make_ndarray(input_data))
    predictions = model(preprocessed_input)
    return {'predictions': predictions}



tf.saved_model.save(
    model,
    r"saved_models",
    signatures={
        "inference_fn": predict_with_preprocessing,
        }
)


Issue:
After successfully training my model and defining a custom preprocessing function, I attempt to save the model along with the preprocessing function using tf.saved_model.save(). However, I encounter the following error:
AttributeError: in user code:
File "<ipython-input-77-066eaabcc7ee>", line 3, in predict_with_preprocessing  *
    preprocessed_input = npre(tf.make_ndarray(input_data))

AttributeError: 'SymbolicTensor' object has no attribute 'tensor_shape'

Details:
I have defined a custom preprocessing function npre() that operates on NumPy arrays.
I use this function to preprocess the data before training the model.
When attempting to save the model along with the preprocessing function using tf.saved_model.save(), the error mentioned above occurs.
I've checked the documentation and made sure that the input tensor shape matches the expected shape in the predict_with_preprocessing function signature.
I've tried to debug the issue by examining the tensors involved, but I'm still unable to resolve the error.
